# Como selecionar linhas da tabela A que estão referenciadas numa coluna da tabela B?

Tags: mysql, query

Estou a tentar executar uma consulta à base de dados com vista a recolher todas as linhas da tabela A que se encontrem referenciadas numa coluna da tabela B:

#### Consulta que estou a executar

```sql
-- Consulta a recolher da tabela A as linhas com ID referenciado na tabela B
SELECT A.*
FROM table_eshop_lines A
WHERE A.id IN (
    SELECT REPLACE(B.lines_id, ';', ',') AS ids
    FROM table_eshop B
    WHERE B.id=1
)
```

O resultado esperado seriam 3 linhas, nomeadamente a linha 1, 2 e 3. O que acontece é que apenas recebo a linha 1:

```
┌──────┬───────┬───────┬────────┬────────┬───────┬──────────────┐
│  id  │  pid  │  ref  │  name  │  isbn  │  qtd  │  unit_price  │
├──────┼───────┼───────┼────────┼────────┼───────┼──────────────┤
│ 1    │ 254   │       │ John   │        │ 1     │  25.08       │
└──────┴───────┴───────┴────────┴────────┴───────┴──────────────┘
```

#### Consulta apenas à tabela B

Se executar a consulta da segunda tabela, obtenho os valores desejados:

```sql
-- Consulta a tabela B
SELECT REPLACE(B.lines_id, ';', ',') AS ids
FROM table_eshop B
WHERE B.id=1
```

Vai-me devolver:

```
┌──────────┐
│   ids    │
├──────────┤
│  1,2,3   │
└──────────┘
```

---

#### As tabelas A e B

Em baixo segue a descrição de cada uma das tabelas obtida através do MySQL [DESCRIBE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/describe.html) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>:

```
DESCRIBE `table_eshop_lines` 
┌────────────┬───────────────┬──────┬───────┬─────────┬────────────────┐
│ Field      │ Type          │ Null │  Key  │ Default │ Extra          │
├────────────┼───────────────┼──────┼───────┼─────────┼────────────────┤
│ id         │ int(11)       │ NO   │  PRI  │ NULL    │ auto_increment │
├────────────┼───────────────┼──────┼───────┼─────────┼────────────────┤
│ pid        │ int(11)       │ NO   │       │ NULL    │                │
├────────────┼───────────────┼──────┼───────┼─────────┼────────────────┤
│ ref        │ varchar(200)  │ NO   │       │ NULL    │                │
├────────────┼───────────────┼──────┼───────┼─────────┼────────────────┤
│ name       │ varchar(500)  │ NO   │       │ NULL    │                │
├────────────┼───────────────┼──────┼───────┼─────────┼────────────────┤
│ isbn       │ varchar(500)  │ NO   │       │ NULL    │                │
├────────────┼───────────────┼──────┼───────┼─────────┼────────────────┤
│ qtd        │ int(11)       │ NO   │       │ NULL    │                │
├────────────┼───────────────┼──────┼───────┼─────────┼────────────────┤
│ unit_price │ decimal(10,2) │ NO   │       │ NULL    │                │
└────────────┴───────────────┴──────┴───────┴─────────┴────────────────┘
```

```sql
DESCRIBE `table_eshop` 
┌─────────────┬───────────────┬──────┬───────┬─────────┬────────────────┐
│ Field       │ Type          │ Null │  Key  │ Default │ Extra          │
├─────────────┼───────────────┼──────┼───────┼─────────┼────────────────┤
│ id          │ int(11)       │ NO   │  PRI  │ NULL    │ auto_increment │
├─────────────┼───────────────┼──────┼───────┼─────────┼────────────────┤
│ sid         │ text          │ NO   │       │ NULL    │                │
├─────────────┼───────────────┼──────┼───────┼─────────┼────────────────┤
│ uid         │ int(11)       │ NO   │       │ NULL    │                │
├─────────────┼───────────────┼──────┼───────┼─────────┼────────────────┤
│ lines_id    │ text          │ NO   │       │ NULL    │                │
├─────────────┼───────────────┼──────┼───────┼─────────┼────────────────┤
│ total_goods │ decimal(10,2) │ NO   │       │ NULL    │                │
├─────────────┼───────────────┼──────┼───────┼─────────┼────────────────┤
│ end_time    │ datetime      │ NO   │       │ NULL    │                │
├─────────────┼───────────────┼──────┼───────┼─────────┼────────────────┤
│ status      │ tinyint(1)    │ NO   │       │ NULL    │                │
└─────────────┴───────────────┴──────┴───────┴─────────┴────────────────┘
```

---

## Pergunta:

O que estou a fazer de errado para que quando executo a consulta total que indiquei, ao invés de receber as 3 linhas da tabela `table_eshop_lines`, apenas recebo a primeira linha que contém o valor `1` na coluna `id` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Até onde eu saiba, o operador `IN` funciona somente para listas, i.e. se o seu `select` interno retornasse mais de uma linha ele procuraria o `A.id` em cada uma dessas linhas - em contraste com o caso onde **o próprio SQL** contém a lista a ser buscada em formato texto - `A.id in (1,2,3)`.

Sugiro experimentar a função [`INSTR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) em vez disso:

```sql
SELECT A.*
FROM table_eshop_lines A
WHERE INSTR((
    SELECT concat(';', B.lines_id, ';') AS ids
    FROM table_eshop B
    WHERE B.id=1
), concat(';', A.id, ';')) > 0;
```

[Exemplo no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42f38/2/0).

Ela retorna o índice (baseado em `1`) da primeira ocorrência de uma substring em outra string (ou `0` se não é substring). Como seu valor `B.lines_id` é uma string, então essa condição deve avaliar verdadeira somente quando o `A.id` estiver contido na mesma.

Nota: usei o `CONCAT` para evitar que, por exemplo, `1` fosse encontrado em `11;12;13`. Dessa forma, `;1;` **não é** encontrado em `;11;12;13;`.

Comment: É possível evitar o concat usando mantendo o replace da pergunta, e usando [`find_in_set`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), mas tenho dúvidas se seria vantajoso.

Answer (score 2):

O seu maior problema é que a tabela B está violando a primeira forma normal, pois o campo `lines_id` é um campo multivalorado. Se você puder resolver isso, seu problema fica muito mais fácil.

De qualquer forma, assumindo que você não possa mudar a modelagem, tente isso:

```sql
SELECT A.*
FROM table_eshop_lines A, table_eshop B
WHERE B.id = 1
AND (A.id = B.lines_id
OR B.lines_id LIKE CONCAT("%;", A.id, ";%")
OR B.lines_id LIKE CONCAT(A.id, ";%")
OR B.lines_id LIKE CONCAT("%;", A.id))
```

Comment: Funciona e de certa forma tem uma leitura simples. +1

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select * 
from a 
where FIND_IN_SET(a.id,
                       SELECT REPLACE(B.lines_id, ';', ',') AS ids
                        FROM table_eshop B
                  );
```

Comment: Testei a consulta, mas a mesma não está a funcionar (tive em conta adicionar o nome da tabela ao primeiro `SELECT`).